# In Haskell, can you create an object of a class?

Tags: class, haskell, types

In a Haskell program I'm trying to debug, there is a class defined:

```
class Dictionary d where
  lookupIn :: d -> Word -> String
```

I'd like to create a variable called `runs` and make it of type `Dictionary` so I could use it in the lookupIn function. However, nothing is working. I've tried `type runs = Dictionary`, and even `data runs = Dictionary` but nothing is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Haskell this is not possible. It is possible in other languages with type-class like constructs (Scala, Agda), but it is not possible in Haskell.

It is possible to make an instance of a class in Haskell:

```
instance Dictionary () where
    lookupIn _ _ = "no"
```

And then to use it:

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ lookupIn () "hello"
```

And it is true that instances do act a lot like data -- and they are represented by data at runtime. This is why in other languages you can store instances in variables, and pass them around explicitly.

But, in Haskell, it is not possible to name an instance, or to store it in a variable. That is, you cannot do this, or anything like it:

```
thisInstance :: Dictionary ()
thisInstance = ???
```

The reason is that in Haskell, it is assumed that for every type and typeclass, there can only be *one* instance of that typeclass applied to that type. That is, you can only ever define one `instance Dictionary ()`. Since  there can be only one, there is no point in naming it. This is convenient for Haskell's type inference -- any needed instances can be pulled up to "arguments" (really typeclass constraints) of the current function.

---

Of course it is possible to achieve the same kind of behavior, just not with typeclasses -- records work well for this:

```
data DictionaryType d = DictionaryData { lookupIn :: d -> Word -> String }
```

now `lookupIn` has the type `DictionaryType d -> d -> Word -> String`, which is a literal translation of the typeclass-using type `(Dictionary d) => d -> Word -> String`. And you can use it like this:

```
myDictionary :: DictionaryType ()
myDictionary = DictionaryData (\_ _ -> "no")

main = do
    putStrLn $ lookupIn myDictionary () "hello"
```

Functionally identical to the typeclass solution, the only difference is how syntax and type-checking work.

Comment: In that last part where you try achieving class behaviour, is Dictionary a function??

Comment: `Dictionary` stands for two different things there... a type constructor and a data constructor. Data constructors are a kind of function -- they take the fields of the data and the build an object out of it. I will edit the names to make the distinction clearer.

Answer (score 8):

Haskell **IS NOT** an object oriented language. Typeclass is not class. A variable is not "variable" (although this is irrelevant here), and certainly also is not an object.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414323/does-haskell-support-object-oriented-programming).

P.S. I guess this is homework. Try to learn the language first (even a bit), Haskell is most likely more fun than you think.

Comment: I've been studying it hard, but I still have not fully grasped how classes worked. It's starting to sink in though. And yes I am finding Haskell fun!

Comment: A Haskell type class most certainly is a class!  It is a class (of types) in the mathematical sense of "not quite a set" or "defined by a predicate."

Comment: Mmm, well said Philip... Well, a bad pundit, am I not?

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of it is this:

In an OO language a class defines both a type (i.e. a set of potential values) and a set of other types (i.e. the potential descendant classes).

In Haskell a typeclass defines *only* a set of types (i.e. the potential "instances" of the typeclass). A typeclass is not itself a type.

(Actually I'm skating over the [distinction in set theory](https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/05/07/basics-sets-and-classes) between a set and a class, which is why they are called "typeclasses" not "typesets". But that's not important here.)