# Invoking nested functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nested-function

I have defined a function called `initials` inside a function called `person`, but I can't figure out how to call `initials` outside of `person`:

```
main =
    --I attempted to print the output of the initials function here.
    (putStrLn ((person "firstName" "lastName") . initials)) --Not in scope: `initials'
    --If this function call worked correctly, the output would be "f.l.".

person firstName lastName =
    firstName ++ ["."] ++ lastName
    where
        fullName = firstName ++ " " ++ lastName
        firstInitial = firstName !! 0
        lastInitial = lastName !! 0
        initials = [firstInitial] ++ "." ++ [lastInitial] ++ "."
```

Is it possible to invoke the `initials` function inside the `main` function, even though it is defined inside the `person` function?

Comment: What is the result you're trying to achieve? i.e. suppose the input is "John" and "Doe" for the first and last name. What should the output be?

Comment: @senshin The output would be "J.D.", in that case. I updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `where` does: it just scopes definitions, meaning they can only be used in the item they are attached to, in this case, `initials` can only be used in `person`.

In other words, you are defining a function `person :: String -> String -> [String]` (taking two strings and returning a list of them), where the internal implementation details of this function include some (unused) value called `initials`. It is *not* like a struct or class in other languages, where `initials` is some value that all `person`s can access. (And anyway `person` is just returning a list of strings, not a new type.) Also, `.` is not a field accessor, it is just a convenient helper for function composition.

It seems like you might be wanting to make a `Person` data type, something like

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String, lastName :: String }
```

This is defining `Person` via ["record syntax"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax).

Now, you can write a function that takes a `Person` and returns their initials:

```
-- using pattern matching
initials (Person {firstName = f, lastName = l}) =
    [f !! 0] ++ "." ++ [l !! 0] ++ "."

-- or, using the accessors implicitly defined via record syntax
initials p = [firstName p !! 0] ++ "." ++ [lastName p !! 0] ++ "."
```

This is used like

```
putStrLn (initials (Person { firstName = "first", lastName = "last" }))

-- or, just using positional arguments (which still work with record syntax)
putStrLn (initials (Person "first" "last"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`initials` isn't a function. It's just a variable you've defined in the body of `person`. If you just want to display the initials, that's straightforward:

```
main =
    putStrLn (initials "John" "Doe")

initials :: String -> String -> String
initials firstName lastName = 
    [firstInitial] ++ "." ++ [lastInitial] ++ "."
    where
        firstInitial = firstName !! 0
        lastInitial  =  lastName !! 0
```

In GHCi:

```
*Main> main
J.D.
```

Or, at a slightly higher level of abstraction,

```
main =
    putStrLn (initials ["John", "Queue", "Public"])

initials :: [String] -> String
initials (name:names) = [name !! 0] ++ "." ++ initials names
initials _            = ""
```

In GHCi:

```
*Main> main
J.Q.P.
```

I don't fully understand why you've written the `person` function - it returns "John.Doe" for inputs "John" and "Doe", but I don't see how that is useful for printing the initials "J.D.".