# Grouping functions in Haskell

Tags: oop, haskell

Using Haskell I would like to group functions together as I would using object orientation in other languages. Concretely following the reply to this question

[Does Haskell support object oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414323/does-haskell-support-object-oriented-programming)

let's assume I have a type

```
data Class = Obj { a :: Int -> Int, b :: Int -> Int }
```

and now I want to define several other functions (methods as it were) that are derived from a and b. One way to do this is to define something like

```
c :: Class -> Int -> Int
c obj x = myb (mya x)
    where mya = a obj
          myb = b obj

d :: Class -> Int -> Int
d obj x = myb (myc x)
    where myb = b obj
          myc = c obj
```

However this means that in each <s>regular expression</s> pattern I need to list explicitly (in the ``where'' clause) which other functions I am using. My question is: is there a shorter way to achieve this?

Comment: each "regular expression"?

Comment: The natural way to "group" functions and their data together in Haskell is *modules*.

Comment: What's the purpose exactly? Some kind of inheritance? Perhaps you would be interested in [Why should I prefer composition over inheritance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance)? Maybe you could supply a use-case for when you'd like to use this pattern. Doing OOP-like things in Haskell can have several purposes; are you doing your own research in programming patterns, or trying to re-use patterns already under your belt instead of learning new ones?

Comment: Although *object oriented* programming *can* be achieved in Haskell (in the sense that you can do something rather similar), usually it is not really a good idea to change the paradigm.

Comment: The use case is this: depending on a set of parameters I have two basic rewriting functions on words. Using these I can define derived rewriting functions and eventually obtain a function that computes a normal form. Now the type is supposed to represent the two basic rewriting rules (or equivalently the parameters) and then the derived rules all belong to the same parameters.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned object orientation because now all the alarm bells go off before anyone reads what I'm actually asking.

Comment: Here is the same question without mention of object orientation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897341/partially-evaluate-several-functions-in-haskell

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to avoid typing too much, you can use the `RecordWildCards` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data Class = Obj { a :: Int -> Int, b :: Int -> Int }

f :: Class -> Int -> Int
f Obj{..} x = a x + b x
```

Then you can use it like this: `f (Obj id id) 10 == 20`

Note that this shadows the actual "field accessors", so this doesn't work if you still want to use those in the same function for some reason.

Without extensions, you can also always just write

```
f (Obj a b) x = a x + b x
```

(Record types can still be pattern matched using the regular constructor syntax).

Comment: Thank you! That does address the question but only for the functions a and b. Can I also get rid of the "where myb = b obj"?

Comment: @StefanWitzel I don't understand what you mean? You don't need `myb = b obj` here.

Comment: In defining the function d above, I used the function c. Your solution to not having to write out mya and myb is specific to the fact that those are fields of Class, so it won't work to avoid writing out myc.