# Partially apply several functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, function-composition

Suppose, in Haskell, I have a bunch of functions that all depend on the same parameter type:

```
f :: Par -> a -> b
g :: Par -> b -> c
```

As I'm writing more of these functions that still depend on this parameter type, I can do something like

```
h :: Par -> a -> c
h par = myg . myf
    where myf = f par
          myg = g par
```

However I keep having to write these `where` lines. The question is: can this be avoided?

[Edit: I tried to provide a minimal example to illustrate the problem but apparently the example is too minimal to illustrate what I want. In the actual problem h is of course not just the composition of f and g. So here is some actual code:

There are functions

```
apply :: ChamberLattice -> ChLatword -> ChLatWord
reduce :: ChamberLattice -> ChLatWord -> ChLatWord
```

and I am defining a function

```
chaseTurn :: ChamberLattice -> Turn -> Parity -> ChLatWord -> ChLatWord
chaseTurn cl Straight _ xs = xs
chaseTurn cl t parity xs = if ((turn parity xs) == t)
                           then case myApply xs of
                               (y1:y2:ys) -> (y1:y2:(myChaseTurn t parity ys))
                               ys -> ys
                           else myReduce xs
where myApply = apply cl
      myChaseTurn = chaseTurn cl
      myReduce = reduce cl
```

]

(This question is essentially the same as
[Grouping functions in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894738/grouping-functions-in-haskell)
but there I used some unfortunate words that distracted people.)

Comment: I don't get why you need the `where` clauses here, you can write it as `h par = f par . g par`, or even better `h = liftM2 (.) f g`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How about `h = (.) <$> f <*> g`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann's answer is the pattern I often reach for when I think "I've got this thing I need to pass out to lots of functions and then combine their results". A bit like a fork-join.  E.g. `(&&) <$> p1 <*> p2` is one I use a lot.

Comment: This is a minimal example. In the actual code naming the partially evaluated functions increases readability (IMO), but it would be nice to do this somehow generically: evaluate all of the following 10 functions x at par and call the outcome myx.

Comment: @StefanWitzel: Another option for you, if you've got working code and you're looking for better abstractions, you can submit a piece of code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @SimonShine: Thank you! I may try that. I thought I had a very clear-cut problem that would have a well-known syntactic sugar answer. But it transpires that this is not the case.

Comment: I think if you need access to 10 "properties" of a data object, then something is really wrong with the design. It could in that case be helpful to (a) encapsulate groups of properties that belong together in a new `data` type, and (b) introduce helper functions that each operate on a subset.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I do not (but am trying to) understand why this means that something is wrong with the design. Essentially I do the usual thing of building up increasingly complex functions out of preexisting ones. Just that everything depends on a parameter (a quadruple of integers) and so I need to carry this parameter through in some form.

Comment: @StefanWitzel: then perhaps pattern matching is your friend.

Comment: Terminological note: this is partial application, not partial evaluation. Partial evaluation is an optimization technique that runs code to some degree at compile time, in order to reduce the required work at run time. It's related to supercompilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `h par = f par . g par` a lot, and the `par` stuff starts to clutter.

You can't do `h = f . g`, since the `par` argument must be passed along, too.

So you come up with a high-powered composition operator that will do this for you:

```
-- (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(§) :: (par -> b -> c) -> (par -> a -> b) -> par -> a -> c
(§) f g par = f par . g par
```

Now you can do `h = f § g`. This operator was probably invented before.

Incidentally, partially applied functions are [instances of Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-803). This means you can do:

```
(§) f g par = (do { fpar <- f; gpar <- g; return (fpar . gpar) }) par
```

Or just:

```
(§) f g = do { fpar <- f; gpar <- g; return (fpar . gpar) }
```

*(Here, `fpar` is `f` to which an implicit `par` has been applied. The monad instance makes `par` implicit.)*

If we were to parameterize this do-block:

```
(§) f g = ( \f m1 m2 -> do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) } ) (.) f g
```

And eta-reduce the parameters:

```
(§) = ( \f m1 m2 -> do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) } ) (.)
```

And look on Hoogle for something that looks like this do-block, you'd find `liftM2`:

```
(§) = liftM2 (.)
```

At which point we don't really need to give it a special name, since `liftM2 (.)` is already pretty short.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't fully appreciate your answer until I reconstructed the monad structure of "->". It helped me to think of the type "p -> a" as "a parametrized by p".

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, all functions take one input argument. Sometimes, though, the return value of applying a function is a new function. As a first step, then, you can make that more explicit by putting brackets around the return value of your functions `f` and `g`:

```
f :: Par -> (a -> b)
g :: Par -> (b -> c)
```

Functions are types as well, so we could arbitrarily decide to alias `a -> b` to `φ` (*phi* instead of *f*) and `b -> c` to `γ` (*gamma* instead of *g*). (Yes, when you run out of letters, you reach for the Greek alphabet!)

This means that you can view your functions as having the types

```
f :: Par -> φ
g :: Par -> γ
```

These are both automatically instances of the so-called *reader monad*, which is also an (applicative) functor. Particularly, `(->) Par`, or, if it helps, `Par ->`, is an `Applicative` instance. This means that you can use `pure` and `<*>` with it.

As a first attempt, you can write something like

```
pure (\x y -> (x, y)) <*> f <*> g
```

in order to simply understand how that composition works. That expression has the type `Par -> (φ, γ)`, so to speak. That lambda expression simply takes `x` from the `f` 'container', and `y` from the `g` 'container', and combines them in a tuple. The first element of the tuple has the type `φ`, and the second element has the type `γ`.

Plugging in the definitions of `φ` and `γ`, you get the type `Par -> (a -> b, b -> c)`.

Instead of a return value as a tuple of functions, you want to compose these functions. You can use the function composition operator `.` for that:

```
h = pure (\x y -> y . x) <*> f <*> g
```

Notice that the functions compose from right to left, so `x` (`a -> b`) comes first, followed by `y` (`b -> c`).

You can, however, flip `f` and `g` around:

```
h = pure (\y x -> y . x) <*> g <*> f
```

That explicit lambda expression can then be eta-reduced to:

```
h = pure (.) <*> g <*> f
```

Finally, instead of writing `pure (.) <*>` you can use the infix `<$>` operator:

```
h = (.) <$> g <*> f
```

This function has the type `Par -> a -> c`.

Comment: @WillNess Thank you :)

Comment: just looking out for the next confused newbie. :)

Answer (score 5):

You've discovered the use case for the `Reader` monad, if you can adjust your signatures slightly. If you have

```
f :: a -> Par -> b
g :: b -> Par -> c
```

you can redefine them as

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

f :: a -> Reader Par b
g :: b -> Reader Par c
```

Then you can define `h` using the normal Kleisli composition operator.

```
import Control.Monad

h :: a -> Reader Par c
h = f >=> g
```

(Even without changing the signatures, I think you can write `h = flip (flip f >=> flip g)`.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using implicit parameters (which are not pure Haskell but a ghc language extension, see https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#implicit-parameters).

The code above just becomes

```
f :: (?p :: Par) => a -> b

g :: (?p :: Par) => b -> c

h :: (?p :: Par) => a -> c
h = g . f
```