# How to work with data structures in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm assigned to make a simple program that contains a students array (which should contain students data), I know that Haskell is not an OO programming language, I was looking for a way for structuring my student data, I thought of nesting tuples into arrays and then into the students array, but the problem is that I have different data types (String, int ...etc.) so tuples doesn't work, I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414545/12682028) on Stack Overflow that creates a new data type from what I understood but I failed to implement it, here is what I have tried:

```js
data Student =
  Student { name :: Char
   , surename :: Char 
   , moy1 :: Int
   , coef1 :: Int
   , moy2 :: Int
   , coef2 :: Int
   , moy3 :: Int
   , coef3 :: Int
   , mg :: Int 
   }

main :: IO ()
main = do 
 putStrLn "Enter students data:"
 students <- initializeStudents 10
 putStrLn "calculate student average ?"
 if(reponse == "yes") then putStrLn "Enter the student firstname"
                           first <- getLine
                           // search on the array student for the student with firstname == first 
                           // then 
                           // putStrLn $ "student average is " ++  calculateData student
 else putStrLn "Okey"

 initializeStudents :: Int -> [Student]
 initializeStudents count = map (\_ -> Student "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ) [1..count]


calculateData :: student -> Int
calculateData student = (a +  b +  c) / d
                        where a = student.moy1 * student.coef1
                              b = student.moy2 * student.coef2
                              c = student.moy3 * student.coef3
                              d = student.coef1 + student.coef2 + student.coef3


saisirDonnees:: Int -> [student] -> IO [student]
saisirDonnees 0 studentsSoFar = return studentsSoFar
saisirDonnees n studentsSoFar = do
  student <- getLine
  saisirDonnees(n-1) (studentsSoFar ++ [student])
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: you don't need the name :: Char-> Char stuff it's just type Char, same for all of your data student

Comment: @dave Alright , do i need the hashable package to do that structure ?

Comment: no but you need data student = student{...}

Comment: @dave ok i updated that now it is okey ?

Comment: your construction of students is a bit confusing me atm

Comment: as saisirDonnees doesn't take an int

Comment: One very important thing to note is that the names of both types and data constructors must begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: You really need to work through a tutorial. `student . moy1` isn't how you access a field of a record (not yet, anyway; there is a proposal to add that as syntax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do as the question is very broad. But, here are some examples that may help understanding...

Define your Student data type:

```
data Student = Student {
   name :: String,
   grade :: Int
}
```

You want a list of default students? Create it like this:

```
initializeStudents :: Int -> [Student]
initializeStudents count = map (\_ -> Student "" 0) [1..count]
```

You could also read the students in from disk, that would require use of IO monad so is beyond scope of these basics.

You want to sum the grades of a list of students? Do it like this:

```
sumGrades :: [Student] -> Int
sumGrades students = sum $ map grade students
```

You want to get the average grade of a list of students? Do it like this:

```
averageGrades :: [Student] -> Double
averageGrades students = fromIntegral (sumGrades students) / fromIntegral (length students)
```

You want to print the average grade of students in the IO monad? You can do so like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let students = initializeStudents 10

  let averageGrade = averageGrades students

  print averageGrade
```

Do you want to stub out a list of actual students instead of the default ones and then print the average grade of the stubbed list? Do it like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let students = [Student "Tim" 10, Student "Bob" 25, Student "Alice" 19]

  let averageGrade = averageGrades students

  print averageGrade
```

To bring this all together, a simple program that asks the user how many student records they want to input, then asks them to input each record and then finally prints the average grade of the students:

```
data Student = Student {
    name :: String,
    grade :: Int
} deriving (Read, Show)

sumGrades :: [Student] -> Int
sumGrades students = sum $ map grade students

averageGrades :: [Student] -> Double
averageGrades students = fromIntegral (sumGrades students) / fromIntegral (length students)

readStudentLines :: Int -> IO [Student]
readStudentLines 0 = return []
readStudentLines count = do
  current <- fmap (\student -> read student :: Student) getLine
  theRest <- readStudentLines (count -1)
  return $ current : theRest

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "How many student records do you wish to enter? (Must be int)"

  numberStudents <- readLn :: IO Int

  putStrLn $ "Start entering your " ++ show numberStudents ++ " student records"
  putStrLn "(Note, they must be in the format: Student {name, grade} )"
  putStrLn $ "For instance: " ++ show (Student "Tom" 10)

  students <- readStudentLines numberStudents

  let averageGrade = averageGrades students

  print averageGrade
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer , i tried to implement that with ` main = do initializeStudents 10` and i got the following error ` Couldn't match type [] with IO
      Expected type: IO Student
        Actual type: [Student]`

Comment: Could you post the full "new" code in your answer as an edit so I can take a look?

Comment: I think I know what's going on, and it has to do with the IO monad, but I'll need to see the code to be sure

Comment: I will edit my answer to show a use case inside the IO monad of the code I gave.

Comment: Alright , That would be better since i have to take the students data from the command line

Comment: Ah you need to read the students data in from user input?

Comment: For instance, the CLI will ask for the user to input `n` students data and then print the average once the user has confirmed the `nth` student?

Comment: yep or a text file both are fine

Comment: Ok, that's a little more complex. Give me about 30 minutes to knock it up

Comment: a text file will contain 10 elements of type `Student` the program should read them ... and initialize the student array with that , Or initialize it with "" and 0 and then fill them with user input ... i think the "txt" file is much easier

Comment: That is s too kind from you , i would do the work if you can guide me up

Comment: How can i access specific property inside my `Student` data , as you can see on my `calculateData ` function im trying to calculate the average of the student and put the result in the property called `mg`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full program that asks the user for a student record number, then asks the user to input that many student records before finally printing the average grade of the inputted student records.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the program ? When i input 1 student then i type exactly `Student { "Tom" , 10 }` i get `Prelude.read: no parse` i've tried similar other formats too but didn't pass

Comment: That's the easter egg for you to figure out (you can't have your assignment for free). If you enter 2, then it will parse the first but fail on the second. Good luck sir :-)

Comment: Haha alright buddy thanks for the help