# How to inherit fields in a data constructor?

Tags: oop, haskell

I am new to Haskell and want to realize this C# code in Haskell. I want to inherit the field `"title"` or make it required to all products, but all examples that I founded are about functions but not fields.

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public string title;

    public string getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
}

public class Videotape : Product
{
}

public class Book : Product
{
    public string authorName;
}
```

Comment: Haskell is not an OOP language so doesn't have inheritance, so you can't "translate" this directly. The question you have to ask yourself is, what problem are you actually trying to solve, and then find a way to solve it with what Haskell gives you.

Comment: "I have this code I've written in language A I already know; how would I write the same thing in language B I'm learning" works very well as a learning strategy when the languages are fairly similar. It can appear to be a good *general* approach to learning new languages, but that's merely because OOP languages are very popular, so most of the times when a programmer learns a new language it's going from one OOP language to another. Haskell isn't similar enough to OOP languages for this to work well. Better to start with a tutorial or book teaching you about features Haskell *does* have.

Comment: You are probably better of if you completely forget inheritance ever was a thing. While type classes exist it is rare to use them when taking your first walk in Haskell land. In fact it is often a sign of "you are doing it wrong". This of course is highly subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell is not an object-oriented language, so the concept of inheritance does not exist directly. There are numerous approaches toward similar things, and picking the right one would need more context.

One approach would be as follows.

You can look at inheritance in your example as achieving two things:

- All subclasses of `Product` contain a field `title`
- All subclasses of `Product` support a method `getTitle` that returns a string.

If we look at both these things as separate, The following solution suggests itself.

First, the product datatype:

```
data Product = Product { title :: String }
```

This creates a *datatype* `Product`, with a single *constructor*, also called `Product`, containing a single *field*, of type `String`, called `title`. `title` is automatically created as a function of type `Product -> String`.

Now let's create a *typeclass* for `Product`, describing the `getTitle` method. A typeclass is not the same thing as a class from C#/OOP, but is more similar to the concept of an interface.

```
class Product' a where
  getTitle :: a -> String
```

This typeclass declares a single method, `getTitle`, that takes an `a`, where `a` is an *instance* of `Product'`, and returns a String.

Next, we'll define an instance of `Product'` for `Product'`.

```
instance Product' Product where
  getTitle = title
```

This defines `Product` as an instance of `Product'` This enable sit to take the place of `a` where a `Product'` instance is expected. This means `getTitle` can be called on `Product`, so we have to define what that should do. In this case, `getTitle` should simply do the same as `title`, i.e. return the `title` field.

Now let's define the "subclasses":

```
data Videotape = Videotape { vtProduct :: Product }

data Book = Book { bProduct :: Product, authorName :: String }
```

We've created two datatypes. `Videotape` just contains a field of type `Product`. `Book` also adds a field of it's own, `authorName`. (The `Product` fields have to have unique names. Haskell turns each one into a function, and you can't have two functions with the same name in the same module).

Now let's define instances for these types:

```
instance Product' Videotape where
  getTitle vt = getTitle (vtProduct vt)

instance Product' Book where
  getTitle b = getTitle (bProduct b)
```

You can now call `getTitle` on an object of either type and get a `String` corresponding to it's title.

I'm sure there's a lot of terminology and concepts here that are unfamiliar to you, but if you read up about them, you'll likely come to understand how Haskell does many things differently, and broaden your approach to designing and wrting software.

You may find these resources useful:

- [OOP vs type classes](https://wiki.haskell.org/OOP_vs_type_classes) from the Haskell Wiki
- [Does Haskell support object oriented programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414323/does-haskell-support-object-oriented-programming) on SO

Happy Haskelling!